# Control Windows VM from Windows Host

Tags: python, virtualbox

I was wondering if it was possible to control a Windows VM from Windows by using python scripts (principally).
By controlling i mean click on files, install softwares.

Does anyone know ?

Answer (score 0):

I think with pywin32 is possible.
You can use  COM technology (http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html) and Win32 API calls (http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i.html)

Comment: I'm not sure to know how to connect my computer to the VirtualBox Windows with COM technology. (the VM is a fresh installation of Windows without anything installed)